# Show updated variable on another screen React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, variables

I have my ScreenOne.js file where I have a variable called points with a starting value of 0. I also have some functions in the file that add a value of 10 to the points.

The updated points variable is shown on the ScreenOne and it is updating well. I also want to display the updated points variable in a screen called ScreenTwo.js but that seems to be a problem.

I have already tried to store the updated value in a local storage but it returns null. In this case I try to export the updated variable but it return the variable that has the starting value instead of the updated value.

What could be the best way to transfer and display the updated variable in ScreenTwo?

ScreenOne:

```js
const ScreenOne = ({ navigation }) => {
    let valuePoints = 0
    module.exports.valuePoints = valuePoints;

    if (userInput1.search('No') < 0) {
        console.log('Wrong answer!')
    } else {
        valuePoints += 10
    }

    if (userInput2.search('Yes') < 0) {
        console.log('Wrong answer!')
    } else {
        valuePoints += 10
    }

    return (
        <ScreenContainer>
            <ScrollView style={{ flex: 1, width: '100%' }}>
                <PointsAmount>
                    {valuePoints}  //Here it displays 20
                </PointsAmount>
            </ScrollView>
        </ScreenContainer>
    )
}

export default ScreenOne;
```

ScreenTwo:

```js
const ScreenTwo = ({ }) => {
    const {valuePoints} = require('../screens/ScreenOne');

    return (
        <PointsContainer>
            <ScrollView style={{flex:1, width: '100%'}}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('MyTabs1')} >
                <ScoreCard header='Points gained' points={valuePoints} goal={100} /> //Here it should display 20 but instead it displays 0
            </TouchableOpacity>
            </ScrollView>
        </PointsContainer>
    )
}

export default ScreenTwo;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the docs for the [context in react](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#contextprovider).

You need to create a context that will be wrapping your `App`.

```
const [points, setPoints] = useState(0);

<Context.Provider value={{points, setPoints}}>
  Your app
</Context.Provider>
```

Then in your `ScreenOne` and `ScreenTwo` you can get and set the value with:

```
  const {
    points, setPoints
  } = useContext(Context);
```